# HTML/php Parser error

Tags: php, html

I was running through the tutorial on http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/online-file-storage-with-php/comment-page-2/#comments
and it was working fine until:

```
if(strlen($message) > 0)
{
    $message = '<p class="error">' . $message . '</p>';
}
```

This line of php is found in index.php. When I few the page in firefox, it looks like the php parser stops at the greater than. Can I escape the character? Do I need to?

EDIT: All the php code:

```
<?php 
//Load the settings
require_once("settings.php");

$message = "";
//Has the user uploaded something?
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{
    $target_path = Settings::$uploadFolder;
    $target_path = $target_path . time() . '_' . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

    //Check the password to verify legal upload
    if($_POST['password'] != Settings::$password)
    {
        $message = "Invalid Password!";
    }
    else
    {
        //Try to move the uploaded file into the designated folder
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            $message = "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). 
            " has been uploaded";
        } else{
            $message = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
        }

    //Clear the array
    unset($_FILES['file']);
}


if(strlen($message) > 0)
{
    $message = '<p class="error">' . $message . '</p>';
}    
?>
<html> ... </html> //my html code
```

Comment: If the code is contained with the normal `<?php` and `?>` then I cannot see a problem with it. You certainly shouldn't need to escape the `>` character

Comment: What is the output that the browser receives (the HTML source)?

Comment: I initialize it as $message = "";

Comment: paste the error message here, it will help much

Comment: what you mean by `php parser stops` ? Are you saying `$message` is not printing the output in your browser?

Comment: Only way I think is, you didn't use `echo $message` in the HTML part below.

Comment: What is your HTML / are the `<html>` tags being displayed in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `>` won't cause the PHP parser to stop.

Without seeing the HTML output by the server, it is hard to say for sure, but since the `>` is the first `>` in the file it seems likely that the PHP parser *never starts* and the browser treats everything between the `<?php` at the start of the file and the `strlen($message) >` **as a tag**.

You need to access the PHP through a web server with PHP installed and configured to process that file (which is typically done by giving it a .php file extension).

Comment: This is probably accurate. I "fixed" the "> problem" by taking yoeriboven's answer, but it then fails at the next "."

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
if(!empty($message)){
    $message = '<p class="error">'.$message.'</p>';
}
```

But why don't you directly assign the paragraph tags to the error message instead of first assigning the error message to `$message` and then the paragraph tags?

Comment: To answer your question, here's why I'd do it: You may want to add multiple error messages for different cases, so why would you double the markup for every message.

Comment: And add the HTML MarkUp to every item? What for? In this case, I'd still add it to every loop item and/or the container.

Comment: This almost works, but then it fails at the '.' on ".$message."

Answer (score 0):

there is not any error in the if condition its working fine

[image]

the possible problem in the

1. `if(isset($_FILES['file']))`
2. `if($_POST['password'] != Settings::$password)`
3. `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path))`

if you are not getting in the if body it mean the problem in

```
  if(isset($_FILES['file']))
```

because if it fase than   `$message = "";`

Comment: It seems to fail before that.

Answer (score -1):

Always use **Yoda Conditions** and write such statements in (the) reverse(d) order (you're normally used to:

```
if ( 0 !== strlen( $message ) )
{
    $message = 'Hello World!';
}
```

Anyway, you could also simply check for `! empty( $message )`

Comment: While this is popular advice, it doesn't explain why the code in the question doesn't work.

Comment: No, but it is a way to get error output, which won't happen in the reverse order